# how to simplify <img src="img/java.jpg" th:src="@{'img/'+${book.image}}" height="60"/>

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new to SpringBoot,
The whole code of html is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7w5QCGNYQG/)

My question is:

Is there a way to simplify this code:

`<img src="img/java.jpg" th:src="@{'img/'+${book.image}}" height="60"/>`

the java.jpg is already contained in book.image.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the src attribute. This is anyway not rendered by thymeleaf

```
<img th:src="@{'img/'+${book.image}}" height="60"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [standard url syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#using-expressions-in-urls), your url would look like this:

```
<img th:src="@{img/{image}(image=${book.image})}" height="60"/>
```

It is a little more verbose, but you don't have to use string concatenation.

You could also represent it as this using [literal substitution](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions).

```
<img th:src="|img/${book.image}|" height="60"/>
```